# Errors with event.preventdefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't work

JS:

```
    var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    var currentPage = currentPath.substring(currentPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        $(function() { 

            $("#shoutBox").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var values = $('#shoutBox').serialize();

                $.post("shoutbox.php", values)

                .done(function(data) {
                    $('input:text[name=shout]').val("JE SHOUT IS GEPOST! WACHT 1 MINUUT!");
                    $('input:text[name=shout]').attr('readonly', true);
                    setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $('input:text[name=shout]').val("JE KAN EEN NIEUWE SHOUT MAKEN!");
                            $('input:text[name=shout]').attr('readonly', false);
                        }, 60000);
                });
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("#newName").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var valuen = $('#newName').serialize();

                $.post("shoutbox.php", valuen)

                .done(function(data) {
                    reload();
                });
            });
        });

    function to_new_page(link)
    {
        $("#content").fadeOut(function()
            {
                $(this).load(link+" #content", function()
                {
                    $(this).fadeIn();
                })
            });
        history.pushState({change: "page"}, "RandomRadio", "/"+link);
    }

    function reload()
    {
        to_new_page(currentPage);
    }
```

Form #shoutBox works sucessfully.
But when I submit the form #newName twice, it will refresh the page.

Comment: Yes, probably because after you submitted the first time the AJAX request for the first time completed and you call `reload()` yourself. What did you expect?

Comment: It will show the #shoutBox form, but when you submit that, it will even just reload. Reload will fade out the page and will fade in a reloaded page.But #newName calls $.post("shoutbox.php") twice, one getted and one posted, and I don't know why he is making a getted request.

Comment: Oh wait, I probably misunderstood you. So you are saying that the `#shoutBox` form works as it should but if you submitted `#newName` twice it stops working?

Comment: it seems like `to_new_page` method reloads something. I bet you gen new `#newName` form and sumbit event is not binded. Use a delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because your `.done` calls `reload()`?

Nevertheless, I would add `return false;`

```
$("#newName").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var valuen = $('#newName').serialize();

            $.post("shoutbox.php", valuen)

            .done(function(data) {
                reload();
            });
            return false;
        });
```

And please, fix your quotation. Either choose single or double quotes and stick to that.

Comment: Thanks for the quotes-tip. I will use " :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix :)

I added a id to my submit buttons and used this

```
    $("#submitshout").live("click", function(event){
```

instead of

```
    $("#shoutBox").submit(function(event) {
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that as of jQuery 1.7 the .live() is deprecated. If I were you, i would check that I use the latest jQuery and instead of .live() I'd use .on() instead to attach event handlers. Just to be on the safe side.